# How to load object from sbt ProjectPlugin.scala in scala object

Tags: scala, sbt

We have multiple projects in sbt based project (as below) and exploring how can I get the app jar name at run time from within a scala object e.g. "project1-v1.jar".

Separate jar is created for each project using **'sbt assembly'**

**Project Structure**

```
Project1
-- main
|   |  |-- resources
|   |  |-- scala
|   |       |-- Test.scala
                import project1._ //=> Is is possible to load from ProjectPlugin.scala?
                val JarName = s"$name-$version"
Project2
.
.
project
  ProjectPlugin.scala
    import sbt._
                import sbt._

                object project1{
                  name := "project1",
                  version := "v1"
                }

                object project2{
                  name := "project2",
                  version := "v2"
                }
.
.
build.sbt
```

Is it possible to extract name/version from ProjectPlugin.scala as that's the 1 place we maintain the version which changes every sprint. I couldn't see ProjectPlugin.scala zipped in the jar file so bit skeptical

or is there any other cleaner alternative to achive that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps someone in similar situation I found sbt plugin [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) helped me achieve this.